# Including Liferay .jars in groovy for portlet development

Tags: grails, groovy, import, liferay, portlet

We are developing liferay portlets in groovy using the portlets and liferay portlets plugins. We wanted to find the user ID of the current user logged in. In order to do that, using the com.liferay.model.user class was suggested (from searching on other S.O. questions).

Unfortunately, when we try to import com.liferay.* (or com.liferay.model.user etc.) the grails complier cannot resolve the 'user' class. This makes sense, since the com.liferay folder is not in the grails/lib folder. However, I am unable to find out where to acquire these .jar files to add them to the lib folder in grails.

Am I approaching this wrong?

(Note: I am using Liferay 5.2.3, not the newest version of liferay)

Or, in 5.2.X is there an easier way to get the ID or name of the currently logged in user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

mvnrepository.com isn't a repository itself, it's a search engine for Maven artifacts.

By looking at the "Download jar hyperlink", I see that the liferay jars are available in Maven Central http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/liferay/portal/.

In the repositories section of your BuildConfig.groovy, make sure that the following line is there

```
mavenCentral()
```

I think the `portal-impl` artifact contains *com.liferay.model.user.** related classes which are what you're looking for.

In that case you would have the following dependency in your `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
compile 'com.liferay.portal:portal-impl:5.2.3'
```

If you require additional liferay classes, assuming you have liferay running somewhere, you could search the jars for a specific class name (http://java.net/projects/jarscan). Once you know the jar name, you can search it on `mvnrepository.com` and add the relevant dependency to your `BuildConfig.groovy`.

Hope it helps.

---

You can reference liferay dependencies in your BuildConfig.groovy. You would need to confirm the repository URL and then it should be fine.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.liferay.portal

You could exclude those dependencies from packaging.

Comment: rimero: we have added both of these and have had no success importing 'com.liferay.portal'  =====> 

    repositories{
 
    mavenRepo "http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/"
     }
     dependencies {
         // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'com pile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg. 
 
    runtime 'com.liferay.portal:portal-service:5.2.3'    '

Comment: also we added mavenRepo "mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.liferay.portal"